# Single word for "making someone work hard to achieve perfection"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which describes this situations: I will *Train you day and night* until you become the ultimate champion of your domain.

So I am looking for a word to replace *Train you day and night*

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How much you paying for that?

Comment: If it's a made-up word made up of multiple words then it's no longer a single word, is it? It's a compound word... at best. Neologisms are off topic on EL&U I'm afraid.

Comment: I deleted my comment, single word is quite fine for me.

Comment: You want *drive*, or an appropriate synonym

Comment: I suggest that's not possible, Kshitij. The closest you could get might indeed be JonLarby's *drive* but try it, please…

Does *I will drive until… (anything)* work?

Exactly why did you ask for a single word, rather than a shorter phrase?

Answer (score 2):

Consider *push*.

> **Push** *verb*
>   3 *with object* Compel or urge (someone) to do something, especially to work hard.
>    ‘I only remember one teacher pushing me to work harder on my academic pursuits.’
>   ‘Tiburce always believed in me, and always pushed me to work hard.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/push)

Your sentence then becomes:

- I will *push you* until you become the ultimate champion of your domain.